# Is it possible using powershell or batch scripting to change the meeting organizer for a lot of meetings in one go?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2003, outlook-2007

We have an exchange 2003 server, and now for one of my users I've created a separate mailbox for organising meetings for all users. Now I want to move all her existing meetings scheduled for all users to be organised by the new mailbox. Is it possible to do so using scripts or do we need to manually cancel each meeting and then organise from the new mailbox?

The new mailbox has delegated editor permissions to the user, who is using outlook 2007.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, at least not back with Exchange 2003.  Maybe 2013 has some functionality around this with Powershell, but not back then.

You can't simply change meeting organizers.  At a minimum this "script" would have to find the meetings, catalog the meetings, then delete and recreate the meetings with the new organizer, which would in turn cause new meeting invites to go out to the recipients.  I've never seen a script such as this in the wild, especially when talking about Exchange 2003.

**However, here's my advice:**

Just inform the user to start using the new mailbox going forward for new meetings, and to let people know that they are using this new mailbox as the "organizer" so that people don't go "what is this?".  For past meetings who cares....and for future meetings if it is a really big deal and they are OK with disturbing the attendees again with a cancellation and then new invitation, then it can be done manually.